# adding a facet to the slush marklogic example

Tags: marklogic, facet

I spend most of the afternoon trying to add a facet to an example application based on the [marklogic slush template](https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node).

It has a facet on eyeColor based on an element range index.

sample data can be found [here](https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node/tree/master/app/templates/sample-data)

My goal is to add a facet on gender , which is also an element in the example json data. So I added an element range index on localname gender. Same collation endpoint.

Then I **Reindexed**

Now I try to understand if I need additional changes in the front end application before the facet turns up in the application.

From the backend I try to understand how I can see which facets (or contraints) are available on my search call using an example xquery on the console. Seems I cannot find the right search:search function to retrieve the facet information from the console, not even the existing one on eyeColor.

If I know what I want I can pass a constrained in the options parameter, but is seems the front-end is not aware of the specific facets the search-api returns or am I wrong?

On the console I tried:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search(" ",
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
      <return-results>true</return-results>
      <return-facets>true</return-facets>
      <constraint name="eyeColor">
    <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint/" type="xs:string">
    </range>
  </constraint>
    </options>)
```

But that does not contain facet results...

Yes I read most of existing questions on ML facets here at SO but no luck still...

Can anyone set me on the right track here?

hugo

Comment: ok on the rest end-point I can see the eyeColor constraint now http://ml8-base-ml1:8050/v1/config/query/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I got it...
you have to add the option to the rest api options in the folder app-root/rest-api/config/options/all.xml

add an option (gender) like

```
  <search:constraint name="gender">
    <search:range type="xs:string" facet="true" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint">
      <search:facet-option>limit=5</search:facet-option>
      <search:facet-option>frequency-order</search:facet-option>
      <search:facet-option>descending</search:facet-option>
      <search:json-property>gender</search:json-property>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
```

deploy again using roxy, rmeber you also need a range index...

Comment: Yes, next to a range index, you need to add a search constraint with facet=true. Put the index in ml-config.xml, and bootstrap. Put the search constraint in all.xml, and deploy rest (or modules). Reindex is not necessary. UI will detect extra facets automatically.